# Can't build ios react native app after upgraded?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a project and I upgraded it from version 0.59.8 To 0.61.2 and follow all the things should I do when [upgrade](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.8&to=0.61.2), but I have some issues when running the app in ios and android,

in ios, I see this error

[image: ios]

in android

> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   Cannot get property 'supportLibVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //this line 
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}" //
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

So how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you do`cd ios && pod install` ?

Comment: @Auticcat absolutely yes

Comment: @Auticcat I just delete Pods file and re run pod install and the error is gone but i see new error relate in react-native-gesture-handler `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.propTypes')

ComponentWrapper
    GestureHandler.js:354:19`